# C.c.-ness of a forcing notion based on an atomless complete Boolean algebra

Tags: set-theory, forcing, boolean-algebras

Given $\mathbb{B} = \langle B, \wedge, \vee, \neg, 0, 1 \rangle$ an atomless complete Boolean algebra that has a $< \mkern-4mu \kappa$-closed dense subset and is $\kappa^+$-c.c., we define a forcing notion $\mathbb{P} = \langle P, \leq \rangle$, as follows:

- a condition $p \in P$ is any partial function from $B^-$ into $B^- \times B^-$ (where $B^- = B - \{1\}$) such that

  1. $|dom(p)| < \kappa$,
  2. whenever we have $a, b \in dom(p)$, $a \vee b \neq 1$, $p(a) = (a_0, a_1)$ and $p(b) = (b_0, b_1)$, we must also have $a_0 \wedge b_1 = 0$ and $a_1 \wedge b_0 = 0$,
  3. (optional) for all $a \in dom(p)$, if $p(a) = (a_0, a_1)$ then $a_0 \vee a_1 = a$.
- $p \leq q$ iff $p$ extends $q$ as a function.

What can we say about the c.c.-ness of $\mathbb{P}$? Also, what additional assumptions on $\mathbb{B}$ and on $\kappa$ are sufficient to make $\mathbb{P}$ $\kappa^+$-c.c.?

EDIT: I try to describe better what the conditions of the forcing entail, and made requirement 3. optional if it helps with answering the questions without that requirement. This is motivated by comments from Andreas Blass.

Comment: If your Boolean algebra is complete, then it is $\lambda$ closed for any $\lambda$.

Comment: @Jonathan, incorrect. In fact quite the opposite is true. A complete boolean algebra is never countably closed.  This is because we can form a countable maximal antichain by taking joins of parts of any maximal antichain.  If $\{ b_n : n < \omega \}$ is such a partition, then let $a_n = \bigvee_{m\geq n} b_m$.  Then the sequence of $a_n$'s gives a descending chain with no lower bound.

Comment: Maybe you intend this, but if $p(a) = (a_0,a_1)$, then there is no $q \leq p$ such that $a_0 \in dom(q)$.

Comment: Can you say a bit about what you want your forcing to do?

Comment: In requirement 2, you say that no two elements of the domain of a condition $p$ should have join equal to 1, but you apparently permit three (or more) elements of that domain to have join 1. That doesn't fit my attempt to understand what this forcing is supposed to do, so I second @MonroeEskew's request for information about the intention behind the forcing.

Comment: Trying to be more specific about my previous comment: Suppose that $a,b,c$ are pairwise disjoint elements of $B$ whose join is $1$, and let $x$ be any element of $B$. Then there's a condition $p$ with domain $\{a,b,c\}$ that sends $a$ to $(a\land x,a\land\neg x)$ and similarly for $b$ and $c$. It seems to me that this $p$ will be an atom in the separative quotient of your forcing; all its extensions in your forcing just add more pairs $(m\land x,m\land\neg x)$ for various $m$ and the same $x$, so they're all compatible. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andrea Blass, I think there is some bad sentence structure to 2. I will edit it. My forcing is supposed to add a function of this kind: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311559/about-the-existence-of-a-particular-kind-of-splitting-function-on-atomless-com/311621

Comment: @Monroe Eskew, given $p(a) = (a_0, a_1)$, $p(a_0)$ will be $(a_0, 0)$.

Comment: In the earlier question that you linked to in your comment here, I don't see any requirement that the pieces $b_0,b_1$ into which $f$ splits an element $b$ must have join $b$. But in the present question, requirement 2 includes $a_0\lor a_1=a$. Is that difference intentional?

Comment: @Andreas Blass, in some sense, yes it is intentional. I wanted to simplify the definition and saw no reason this additional condition will give me trouble that is not already there.

Comment: I have made some edits to my question.

Comment: @MonroeEskew To me $0$ is a lower bound of this sequence but anyway it doesn't matter. Closedness is just not a property of the boolean algebra.

Comment: @Jonathan if you allow 0 to be in the descending sequence in the definition of closure, then the notion trivializes.